# Is it a good practice to modify the datacontext of a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

If I am creating a new control and I need access to something outside of it, is it a good practice to modify the datacontext or should I use the relative data binding like this:

```
{Binding Path=PathToProperty, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

The issue I see with modifying the datacontext is it gets confusing to know what this control can be bind to in the xaml as the datacontext modification occurs in C# and not in xaml.

**EDIT**

Let me reformulate the question, is there any technical reasons why I should or should not modify the datacontext of my control?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by *"modify the datacontext"*?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you creating a `UserControl` or custom `Control`?

Comment: @Mike, Set the datacontext of my control to something else than the application's datacontext.

Comment: @Kevin, Does it make a difference? I'm currently testing for UserControls but it could be either.

Comment: @MaximeTremblay-Savard Personally, I'd say yes it does make a difference. It is my personal belief that a custom `Control` should never be dependent on a behavior of something else and you should never change the DataContext from within the `Control`. I could be a little more flexible with a `UserControl`, but I would not recommend that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, RelativeSource binding is actual if you have clearly defined visual tree, so you can forecast where your Control or UserControl will be placed.

Also, RelativeSource is mostly used to set control properties that define your control face, but not to display business information in control.

To display business information, there is MVVM architecture that allows different DataContexts for different controls. For example - your application can contain information about Customers, Sales and Transactions - so you will have at least three DataContexts. If you want to edit customer information - you will have another DataContext for new Window or UserControl.

You could use one DataContext for the whole application, but such DataContext would not be flexible and it would be hard to extend it (Of course, complexity of such DataContext depends on application complexity)